# Typescript not retaining folder structure when using 'exclude'?

Tags: typescript

Having a server and app folder in the root of a project, both directories appear in the build folder when tsc runs. I.e.:

> Input

```
root/
├── app/
│   ├── app.ts
├── server/
│   ├── index.ts
```

> Output

```
build/
├── app/
│   ├── app.js
├── server/
│   ├── index.js
```

When excluding 'app' in the config, though, there is no 'server' folder anymore and index.js appears directly in the build directory.

Is there some option one can set to keep the behavior consistent and still see the server folder, regardless if its the only one or not?

Thanks

Comment: You should use `rootDir` and `outDir` to control this behavior